# alternative for System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a legacy application where HostingEnivronment.RegisterObject is used.

I have been tasked with converting this to asp.net core 2.0. however I am unable to find a way to either implement this or find an alternative to this in asp.net core 2.0.

the namespace **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal** does not contain the registerobject method nor does it have the IRegisteredObject interface. I am at a loss on how to get this implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to achieve similar goal in asp.net core is to use [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x) interface. It has two properties two `CancellationToken`s,

`ApplicationStopping`:

> The host is performing a graceful shutdown. Requests may still be
>   processing. Shutdown blocks until this event completes.

And `ApplicationStopped`:

> The host is completing a graceful shutdown. All requests should be
>   completely processed. Shutdown blocks until this event completes.

This interface is by default registered in container, so you can just inject it wherever you need. Where you previously called `RegisterObject`, you instead call

```
// or ApplicationStopped
var token = lifeTime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnApplicationStopping);

private void OnApplicationStopping() {
     // will be executed on host shutting down
}
```

And your `OnApplicationStopping` callback will be invoked by runtime on host shutdown. Where you previously would call `UnregisterObject`, you just dispose token returned from `CancellationToken.Register`:

```
token.Dispose();
```

You can also pass these cancellation tokens to operations that expect cancellation tokens and which should not be accidentally interrupted by shutdown.

Comment: This answer is not clear, could you please give more details, what namespace we need to using (or nuget install)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-6.0

This was the OLDER method (now deprecated). To use the older method, add a using statement for: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.

The NEW method is: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Add a using statement for this namespace: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

You might need to install Nuget packages for these if VisualStudio, Mono, etc can't find the namespace.

Comment: Could you please update with clear code examples? Where does `lifeTime` object comes from?

Comment: @Hary it's been 5 years so things has changed a bit. Here is fresh link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0. As mentioned - it's registered by default in asp.net DI so you can inject it wherever you need to use it. For example here they inject to hosted service: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59650230/5311735.